# Keep SwipeRefreshLayout until task is finished running

Tags: java, android

Hi so I have the following code:

In the onCreate:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refreshContent();
            }
        });
```

And in another method:

```
private void refreshContent(){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
            new RefreshScores().execute();
            list.clear();
            list.addAll(db.getTracked());
            db.closeDB();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    },2000);
}
```

Currently, when I pull down near the top of my app, the refresh spinner shows up and starts spinning. It disappears after 2 seconds. However, I want it to remain visible until `RefreshScores().execute()` and `list.clear(); list.addAll(db.getTracked()); db.closeDB();` have occured. The RefreshScores is an AsyncTask. Not really sure how to do this.

Comment: Change the timings for refresh 2000 to 5000 and then try

Comment: @PavanBilagi That'll just make it last for 5 seconds right? There's no guarantee that my other code will have finished yet.

Comment: There is no guarantee but i hope that  new RefreshScores().execute();  Async task will complete in that interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask has a callback named `onPostExecute`. This callback will be invoked in the UI thread when doInBackground() returns. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You may try using

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

directly in this callback, and move other calls which require new data to the callback as well.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for it seems. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Edit

```
 mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                               mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: It says it must be called from the UI thread so that won't work.

Comment: Same place you added the first time

Comment: And then where should I call my async task and the other stuff?